# postgres login via cmd

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I am trying to log into postgres through my cmd. When I type "psql" a password request appears but when I type nothing appears. Seems my keyboard keys have no effect. I can access my pgadmin. I am using version 9.6.

[image: Displayed error].

I am new to this. Thanks for the help in advance.

I am not sure but I believe I am. Here is a shot of my pgAdmin..
[pgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BzjQ.png)

Comment: Sounds as if you are not using the database user `postgres` from pgAdmin, but some other user. Or you are connecting to a different server from pgAdmin

Answer (score 0):

The psql command does not echo your keypresses to the console.  This is the expected behavior due to security considerations.

The password that is being requested is for your system login user, which would have to have login rights to a database in order to function.

To use the same user/password combination that works in pgAdmin try:

```
psql -U {username}
```

and when the password prompt appears, use the one you used from pgAdmin and press enter.

Comment: Thanks Kirk. I tried it but it still doesn't work. I used both my PC password and my pgAdmin password and none of them worked. Is there a way I could force it to echo just to be sure?